# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{na_n}=a$ is in R, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n}a_n}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The question is to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{na_n}=a$ is in R, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n}a_n}=0$.
Also, it asks to show converse is false.

I am try to show that:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n*a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n}*
\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=n*\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=a$.

So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=\frac{a}{n}$.

By using the same property I will have $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt{n}a_n}=\sqrt{n}*\frac{a}{n}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{n}}$.

How to go from here to show it equals 0? Am I understand the question correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Write 
$$
\sqrt{n}a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot na_n
$$
and use the rule of limits of products.

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea. I try the same trick for the other direction, but it seems not work. What should I try to show it is false?

Comment: For the converse: You want a sequence $a_n$ such that $\sqrt{n}a_n\to 0$ but such that $na_n$ is not converging. You only need to find one counter-example. Could you find some $a_n$ that lies inbetween $1/\sqrt{n}$ and $1/n$? What would that give? Ask again if you do not fix it from this hint.

Comment: Thanks again. This helps me a lot to think this type of problems.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot split the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n$ into a product of limits as you did, since $\{n\}$ is a divergent sequence and you aren't given that $\{a_n\}$ converges; and everything you did after this split is just plain wrong. I would have posted a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: This is actually an answer (upvoted to make sure you can comment asap)